# Hour 00:00 automatically convert to 12:00

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my symfony2 form type, I have datetime choice fields which they are Years choice, Months choice, Days choice, Hours choice and Minute choice.

When I save the new record which I keep the hours choice 00 [2015/07/16 00:00]. After success saving, I go to my list and I saw the hours of new record is 12 [2015/07/16 12:00].

1. when I do a select from database, I got date like [2015/07/16 00:00]
2. In my twig, I did

   {{ entity.replyDateTime|date("Y-m-d h:i") }}

Anyone know, how to stop this auto converting and keep it as 00 [2015/07/16 00:00]?

Comment: Please add your form definition and snippet of your list twig template. It looks like it is formatted in 12-hour clock format. 2015/07/16 00:00 is the same like 2015/07/16 12:00 AM. Or you have mistake somewhere and store it badly. What date is stored in database? Do you see 12:00 also in edit action?

Comment: Hi @kba, thanks for replying. The date store look like this [2015-07-16 00:00] and in edit action I also got this bug.

Comment: Ok. Again. Can you show definiton of your form? At least in twig template it is your fault. H is for 24-hour, h for 12-hour. I guess you have similar problem in form definition.

Comment: In my form {{ form_widget( form.replyDateTime ) }}

Comment: I mean definition of form type (from own class or from controller). Do you alter date format in form definition?

Comment: Hi @kba, thanks for your help. I have found solution for my form type here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#view-timezone